# Linking child data to group data Expandable listview Android

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap, expandablelistview

I have an `expandable listview` in my Android project and having trouble linking the child data to the groups. I'm using `ArrayList Hashmaps` but they are unsorted. I get the Group data from one source and than child data from another source.

There is a "ID" value (Key/Value) in both the groups & childs so could use that to link the childs to the groups? Or will I need to repackage the group/child data into a sorted `List` like I see a lot of the expandable listview tutorials/examples out there? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Activity activity;    
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groups;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> child;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DatabaseHandler dbh;
int flag;

static class RowHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView id;
    TextView reference;
    TextView vicinity;
    TextView lastcheck;
    TextView number_checkins;
    TextView user;
    ImageView user_image;
    ImageView checkin;
}

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> e) {
    activity = a;
    groups = d;
    child = e;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    dbh = new DatabaseHandler(activity);

}

public void clearData() {
    // clear the data
    groups.clear();
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return ((HashMap<String, String>)child.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ((HashMap<String, String>)child.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View  
convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RowHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        holder = new RowHolder();
        holder.user_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        holder.user = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RowHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> userList;
    userList = child.get(groupPosition);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(userList.get(MainActivity.KEY_USERIMAGE),    
 holder.user_image);
    holder.user.setText(userList.get(MainActivity.KEY_USER));
    return convertView;
}
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View                

convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    RowHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
        holder = new RowHolder();
        holder.number_checkins = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.number_checkins);
        holder.id = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.id);
        holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.vicinity = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.vicinity);
        holder.lastcheck = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lastcheck);
        holder.checkin = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.check_in);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RowHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> placeList;
    placeList = groups.get(groupPosition);
    holder.id.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_ID));
    holder.name.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
    holder.vicinity.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_VICINITY));
    holder.lastcheck.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_LASTCHECK));
    holder.number_checkins.setText(placeList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NUMBERCHECKINS));       

    return vi;

}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know in which group a specific child is? (Not implementation-wise but just the logic)

Comment: @joz In each group is a unique ID and each child has an ID that matches one of the groups. I don't know the IDs before hand.

Comment: Do the number of ids change over time? (Once the adapter has loaded?)

Comment: @joz No the number of IDs won't change once the adapter has loaded. If the user refreshes the list, there maybe more or less IDs.

Comment: Was This issue resolved? if so, what was the conclusion?